# Как изменить интенсивность канала RGB у изображения

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Программа для os x. Мне нужно изменить интенсивность канала RGB у изображения. Как я могу получить значение пикселей и изменить их при помощи Swift или objective-c?

Comment: Что именно Вы хотите изменить и как? Распишите подробнее.

Comment: @VAndrJ у меня есть изображение, мне надо получить значение RGB каналов для каждого пикселя и изменить их значение(интенсивность).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404240/how-to-change-rgb-value-of-an-image-in-ios.  думаю это может помочь (хоть и пример под iOS, но думаю натолкнет на правильную мысль)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, это берем текущее значение красного, зеленого, синего и изменить их значение?

Пример для 3 каналов:

```
extension NSImage {
    func increaseColorIntensity(byPercent percents: Int) -> NSImage? {
        assert(0...100 ~= percents, "Percents value in 0...100 range")
        guard let cgImageRef = self.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil) else {
            return nil
        }
        let intensityIncrease = CGFloat(percents) / 100
        let width = cgImageRef.width
        let height = cgImageRef.height
        let imageSize = NSSize(width: width, height: height)
        let imageRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imageSize)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bytesPerPixel = 4
        let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
        let bitsPerComponent = 8
        let bitmapByteCount = bytesPerRow * height
        let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bitmapByteCount)
        let context = CGContext(data: rawData,
                                width: width,
                                height: height,
                                bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                space: colorSpace,
                                bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue)
        context?.draw(cgImageRef, in: imageRect)
        var byteIndex = 0
        while byteIndex < bitmapByteCount {
            rawData[byteIndex + 0] = UInt8(min(CGFloat(rawData[byteIndex + 0]) * (1 + intensityIncrease), 255)) // R channel in byteOrderBig
            rawData[byteIndex + 1] = UInt8(min(CGFloat(rawData[byteIndex + 1]) * (1 + intensityIncrease), 255)) // G channel in byteOrderBig
            rawData[byteIndex + 2] = UInt8(min(CGFloat(rawData[byteIndex + 2]) * (1 + intensityIncrease), 255)) // B channel in byteOrderBig
            byteIndex += 4
        }
        let newImage = NSImage(cgImage: context!.makeImage()!, size: imageSize)
        rawData.deinitialize()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

И просто используете:

```
let newImage = image.increaseColorIntensity(byPercent: 20)
```

Можете изменить для каждого канала отдельно, в комментариях к коду посмотрите что где.